How to fix CWE-601: URL Redirection to Untrusted Site ('Open Redirect')
I have code in my application user i have written code for redirection
function redirect(url){
 window.location=url
}

this code is failed in veracode scan stating CWE-601: URL Redirection to Untrusted Site ('Open Redirect')
i have tried with below code as well, same result
window.location= encodeURI(url) 

and also wrote code for custom validation still its not working
function sameOrigin(url) {
  const { host } = window.document.location; // host + port
  const { protocol } = window.document.location;
  const srOrigin = `//${host}`;
  const origin = protocol + srOrigin;
  // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
  const isvalidPath =
    url === origin ||
    url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) === `${origin}  /` ||
    url === srOrigin ||
    url.slice(0, srOrigin.length + 1) === `${origin}  /` ||
    // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
    !/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url);

  return isvalidPath ? url : '/';
}

in my scenario i cant manage all valid urls and cross check with it

"i have tried with below code as well, same result" - the message is not about missing URL encoding, but about the fact that window.location=url could redirect anywhere - like https://malwaresite.xyz. Can the url value somehow be manipulated from the outside, or is your app in full control of them?

its in my app only,after login only he can manipulate with url
